# I can't convert string to int

Tags: c#, type-conversion

i was making a visual studio program that automatically solve some kind of math problems. then i keep failing to convert text from textbox in window form. so i tried every way i found in google to convert string to int but still don't work. so i was looking for solution here but i could't know why this is broken

three textbox is named coefficient_of_absolute, x_coefficient, constant.
and this is part of my code that supposed to convert text of textbox to number

```
MessageBox.Show(coefficient_of_absolute.Text);
MessageBox.Show(coefficient_of_absolute.Text.GetType().ToString());
int coa_int = Convert.ToInt32(coefficient_of_absolute.Text);
```

one messagebox showed that text is 1 and the other showed that type of the text is string
but this program say that Input string is malformed

this text is satan. it stole more than 10hours of my life. please help me

edit)

```
MessageBox.Show(coefficient_of_absolute.Text);
MessageBox.Show(coefficient_of_absolute.Text.GetType().ToString());
int coa_int = int.Parse(coefficient_of_absolute.Text);
```

it didn't work

```
MessageBox.Show(coefficient_of_absolute.Text);
MessageBox.Show(coefficient_of_absolute.Text.GetType().ToString());
int output;
int.TryParse(coefficient_of_absolute.Text, out output);
MessageBox.Show(output.ToString());
```

this made num to zero whatever it is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgUMG.png)

```
MessageBox.Show(coefficient_of_absolute.Text.Length.ToString());
```

cheaking around text revealed length of the text is 1, which means there was nothing around it

Comment: Have you tried `int.Parse`? And please upload your error message (as you receive it) to the question.

Comment: Are there any spaces around that "1"?

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't on some other line?

Comment: i have tried 'int.Parse' and the image is error message i get

Comment: there are no spaces around that "1" and that error message is surely appear where the program convert

Comment: Instead of reading a text box, try converting a simple string variable, containing that "1" - just a sanity check

Comment: If TryParse doesn't succeed, it returns "false" (which you ignore) and sets the out variable to 0 (the default value for int)

Comment: Trying converting a simple string variable "123" was successful, but some reason i don't know, it still can't convert text from textbox. i really hope reinstalling visual studio fix this problem

Comment: What is your current culture? Could it be that the "1" from the latin charset isn't recognised as a valid digit in culture that your app uses? Try and specify the culture (possibly CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string textBoxString = textBox1.Text.ToString();
        int textBoxInt = int.Parse(textBoxString);
        int test = textBoxInt + 1;
        string testText = test.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(testText);
```

converting the variable into string first then converting into int solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

you can try  TryParse instead of Convert.ToInt32 , that way you can check if you catch exception.

```
    int outputNumber;
    bool res = int.TryParse(text1, out outputNumber);
    if (res == false)
    {
        // String is not a number.
    }
```